# Scrolling DataGridView with buttons

Tags: c#, datagridview

Hello I have a code where I inside of a `datagridview` generate buttons with data from sql server database. But now I want to scroll them through buttons. I tried lots of things all gives me error already saw a post about this but nothing worked for me can someone help.

<-----------------------------------My code------------------------------------->

Methods to fill the datagridview:

```
public void TabelaFuncionario()
{
    try
    {
        BDfuncionarios = new DataTable();
        string cmd = "My select string";
        var adpt = fConexao.GetDataAdapter(cmd);
        BDfuncionarios.Clear();
        adpt.Fill(BDfuncionarios);
    }
    catch (Exception r)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(r.Message);
    }
}

public void BotaoFuncionario()
{
    try
    {
        TabelaFuncionario();
        PosXartigo = 1;
        PosYartigo = 1;

        //Apagar o painel todo
        dataGridView1.Controls.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow row in BDfuncionarios.Rows)
        {
            int posicaoX = ((PosXartigo - 1) * Gap_Xartigo) + xInicial + (Largura_BotaoArtigo * (PosXartigo - 1));
            if (posicaoX > maximoxArtigo)
            {
                PosYartigo++; PosXartigo = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                PosXartigo = PosXartigo != 1 ? PosXartigo++ : 1;
            }
            int PontoX = ((PosXartigo - 1) * Gap_Xartigo) + xInicial + (Largura_BotaoArtigo * (PosXartigo - 1));
            int PontoY = ((PosYartigo - 1) * Gap_Yartigo) + yInicial + (Altura_BotaoArtigo * (PosYartigo - 1));
            Button bt1 = new Button();
            bt1.Location = new Point(PontoX, PontoY);
            Mo mo = new Mo();
            mo.codmo = (int)row["Something"];
            mo.nome_func = (string)row["Something"];
            bt1.Name = "Botao" + NBotoes.ToString();
            bt1.Height = Altura_BotaoArtigo;
            bt1.Width = Largura_BotaoArtigo;
            bt1.BackColor = Color.Tan;
            bt1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            bt1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            bt1.Text = mo.nome_func;
            bt1.Tag = mo;
            bt1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;
            bt1.Click += btArtigo_click;
            dataGridView1.Controls.Add(bt1);

            NBotoes++;
            PosXartigo++;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception r)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(r.Message);
    }
}
```

Image of my form (don't know if it helps):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jUg5.jpg

<--------------------------EDITED--------------------------------->

i have tried things like this :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowcount(v=vs.110).aspx

Gives me out of range or something like that

And tried this just now

```
int row = dataGridView1.RowCount;
MessageBox.Show(row+"");
```

And it displays me 0; how can i have buttons inside my grid but have 0 rows?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648872/datagridview-how-to-jump-to-the-selected-row-in-search similar question - involving scrolling to specific rows

Comment: _all gives me error_ . What errors do you get and what have you tried ?

Comment: @NullException i edited the question

Comment: You adding a button to the `Controls` collection. It does not fit in a cell in the `DataGridView`. Have you tried `DataGridViewButtonColumn` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using this panel instead of datagrid for what u wanted it was much better the code will be below:

Methods:

```
public void TabelaFuncionario()
    {

        try
        {
            BDfuncionarios = new DataTable();
            string cmd = "your select";
            var adpt = fConexao.GetDataAdapter(cmd);
            BDfuncionarios.Clear();
            adpt.Fill(BDfuncionarios);
        }
        catch (Exception r)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(r.Message);
        }
    }

    public void BotaoFuncionario()
    {
        try
        {

            TabelaFuncionario();
            PosXartigo = 1;
            PosYartigo = 1;

            //Apagar o painel todo
            panel2.Controls.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow row in BDfuncionarios.Rows)
            {
                int posicaoX = ((PosXartigo - 1) * Gap_Xartigo) + xInicial + (Largura_BotaoArtigo * (PosXartigo - 1));
                if (posicaoX > maximoxArtigo)
                {
                    PosYartigo++; PosXartigo = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    PosXartigo = PosXartigo != 1 ? PosXartigo++ : 1;
                }
                int PontoX = ((PosXartigo - 1) * Gap_Xartigo) + xInicial + (Largura_BotaoArtigo * (PosXartigo - 1));
                int PontoY = ((PosYartigo - 1) * Gap_Yartigo) + yInicial + (Altura_BotaoArtigo * (PosYartigo - 1));
                Button bt1 = new Button();
                bt1.Location = new Point(PontoX, PontoY);
                Mo mo = new Mo();
                mo.codmo = (int)row["Var1"];
                mo.nome_func = (string)row["Var2"];

                bt1.Name = "Botao" + NBotoes.ToString();
                bt1.Height = Altura_BotaoArtigo;
                bt1.Width = Largura_BotaoArtigo;
                bt1.BackColor = Color.Tan;
                bt1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
                bt1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                bt1.Text = mo.nome_func;
                bt1.Tag = mo;
                bt1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;
                bt1.Click += btFuncionario_click;
                panel2.Controls.Add(bt1);

                NBotoes++;
                PosXartigo++;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception r)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(r.Message);

        }
    }
```

Now the PainelExtension class:

```
public static class PanelExtension
{
    public static void ScrollDown(this Panel p, int pos)
    {
        //pos passed in should be positive
        using (Control c = new Control() { Parent = p, Height = 1, Top = p.ClientSize.Height + pos })
        {
            p.ScrollControlIntoView(c);
        }
    }
    public static void ScrollUp(this Panel p, int pos)
    {
        //pos passed in should be negative
        using (Control c = new Control() { Parent = p, Height = 1, Top = pos })
        {
            p.ScrollControlIntoView(c);
        }
    }
}
```

The up and down button click:

```
private void upbt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (i >= 0) i = -1;
        panel2.ScrollUp(i=i-30);
    }

    private void downbt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (i < 0) i = 0;
        panel2.ScrollDown(i=i+20);
    }
```

I got it to work like this maybe there were other ways to do it i choose this one.